# The type java.sql.SQLException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource

Tags: java, spring

```
package com.test.redis.config;

import com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource;
import com.alibaba.druid.support.http.StatViewServlet;
import com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter;
 

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.SQLException;
```

IDEA SpringTooSuit4, maven pom.xml config jpa.

---

javax.sql.DataSource,java.sql.SQLException can not be resolved.

no idea ............
expect import success

Comment: Try this one: `<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.sql-api</artifactId>
    <version>XX.XX.XX</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to import this maven library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.32</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem  is not resolved. PS, my db is postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

it should be jre compatibility issue, jre1.8 is ok

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).